# EmEditor Professionalで元に戻す情報を破棄して速くする設定はマクロ側で設定できますでしょうか？

Tags: emeditor

お世話になっております。
https://jp.emeditor.com/forums/topic/emeditor-professional-7-50-alpha-4/

こちらの記事を見ました。
元に戻す情報を蓄積しなければに速くする設定が実行中の画面に出てきますが、これは最初からマクロ側のコードで最初から設定できますでしょうか？

特定のマクロの動作のときだけ元に戻す必要はないので、そのマクロのときは適応して、普段の通常作業ときは元に戻せるようにしたいのです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

マクロでは、

```
DiscardUndo = true;
```

と指定することにより、一時的に元に戻す情報を破棄します。

また、マクロではありませんが、`ツール` メニューの `カスタマイズ` を選択し、`カスタマイズ` ダイアログ ボックスの `編集` ページの `常に長い元に戻す情報を破棄して速くする` チェック ボックスを設定してください。このオプションは、長い情報のみ元に戻す情報を破棄し、短い情報の場合には破棄せずに普通に使用することができます。

Comment: DiscardUndo = true;で出来ました。ありがとうございます。